# How to render Multiple forms in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have created a one to many relationship and I need to keep this relationship going. Is it okay to create multi forms also? I am new to python. Is it possible to create two modelforms with two models and put in the views.py file.How do I do that?
But I get this error of "Select a valid choice. Male is not one of the available choices" in my web form.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Diseases, Gender


class GenderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Diseases
        fields = ['gender_disease', 'diseases']
```

Models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Count
from itertools import groupby
Gender_Choice = (
    ('Male', 'MALE'),
    ('Female', 'FEMALE'),
)

Diseases_Choice= (
    ('Cholera', 'CHOLERA'),
    ('HIV', 'HIV'),
    ('Malaria', 'MALARIA'),
    ('Typhoid', 'TYPHOID'),
    ('Measles', 'MEASLES'),
)


class Gender(models.Model):
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=19, choices=Gender_Choice , default='Male')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender


class Diseases(models.Model):
    gender_disease = models.ForeignKey(Gender, choices=Gender_Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    diseases = models.CharField(max_length=19, choices=Diseases_Choice , default='Malaria')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diseases
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import GenderForm
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from . models import Gender, Diseases
from django.db.models import Count
from django.views.generic.list import ListView


class CreateMyModelView(CreateView):
    model = Diseases
    form_class = GenderForm
    template_name = 'checkmate/name.html'
    success_url = 'result'
    context_object_name = 'name'


class MyModelListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'checkmate/result.html'
    context_object_name = 'Results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = GenderForm.objects.values('Gender', 'Diseases').annotate(Patients=Count('*'))
        return queryset
```

name.html

```
{% extends 'checkmate/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
<br>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" action="btn btn-success" value="Vote"/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

result.html

```
{% extends 'checkmate/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
<h2>Disease Count</h2>
<br>
<ul>
    {% for item in Results %}
    <li> <b>{{item.Gender}} - {{item.Diseases}} - {{ item.Patients}} votes</b></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<br>

{% endblock %}
```

Desired Output

```
Male Malaria 4votes
Male HIV  3votes
Female HIV 5votes
```

Comment: I think you should use ManytoMany relationship in the first hand because a gender can have many diseases and a disease can have many genders. Can you share the output as well?

Comment: Can you please share the error your getting.

Comment: I am having issues in the view.py file, it seems to be giving an error.I don't know how to go about the views.py part

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I don't think it's necessary for Gender to have an entire model if it only has two possible options. Instead let the Gender options be the options for the gender field under the disease model. 

With that said,  you need to be more specific about the error you're having.

Comment: I get this error of "Select a valid choice. Male is not one of the available choices" in my web form. when I select either male or female in the webform

Comment: show us you template, I expect that your gender selection input field has 'Male' and 'Female' as values where it should have the list of Gender objects (ids as values). Your form is expecting an id to select the appropriate `gender_diseases` not a string 'male' of 'female'.

Comment: just added the name.html and result.html file

Comment: Just clear me one thing, you want to add your form to your listview in your views? And I did not get when you said two forms, what is the second form for?

Comment: I want a form that pops a dropdown button Gender: Male, female and Diseases: Malaria, HIV, Fever. I have to use a one to many relationship(Gender having multiple diseases). I really don't know how to go about it. I was just trying the listviews.